# Permitir requisições apenas de uma rota específica node NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express.js, cors

Estou tentando criar um gateway API, que está indo muito bem. No entanto, ao tentar fazer com que um microserviço aceite SOMENTE requisições pelo gateway, estou tendo problema. Quero que qualquer requisição externa seja bloqueada, apenas requisições internas possam ser aceitas.

Tentei interceptar as requisições pelo request e pelo response das rotas utilizando o express, mas não tem nenhuma propriedade que me diga isso. Tentei utilizar o módulo "cors", mas sempre que dou um console.log na propriedade "origin" que vem dele, vem como nula.

Alguém poderia me dar um norte para isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, você pode fazer isso de 2 maneiras:

1° Na sua aplicação, verificando o IP de origem das requests, pode obtê-lo com o comando `request.connection.remoteAddress`. Aí é só colocar uma validação nas suas rotas.

2° Bloquear todas as requisições de outros IP pelo firewall.

Eu aconselho utilizar a segunda opção, somente utilizaria a primeira se não tivesse jeito algum de implementar o bloqueio pelo firewall. Isso porque o firewall já é desenvolvido para este propósito, além de ficar mais "limpa" sua aplicação que vai ser mais fácil para dar manutenção.